# github forking and upstream changes

Tags: git, open-source, github

Say I want to contribute to an open source project named `SuperOSS`. I'll create my own fork, let's call it `MyOSS`. I'll make changes to the `MyOSS` repo and make a pull request. At that point my git repo looks like this:

```
remote.origin = MyOSS
remote.upstream = SuperOSS
```

Say my pull request never gets added and a few months pass. At that point, what do I need to do to submit another pull requests? Do I need to rebase `SuperOSS` on top of `MyOSS` and just overwrite my pull request that never got added? Is there a better way?

At first I was going to delete the `MyOSS` repo and re-fork `SuperOSS` but there must be a better way than that.

Comment: Like ksol says. And then to save your pull request that never got accepted make a new branch for it. And then git reset -- hard your master back to before you started making changes and then pull from upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your master should be clean (meaning, reflect the original repo state), and your features proposal in a separate branch per feature, ideally. That way, if your feature never get accepted, it does not prevent you from starting another feature branch from master.